# Events between number of threads c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, software-design

If I want thread A to receive its packets and process them, and some thread B can at some point change the socket's IP address.

**So the thing that need to be done here is:**
Thread A must start on listening on the new IP and thread B must somehow tell that to thread A.

Any suggestions? please it is very important for me.

Comment: It interests me, but what libraries are you using? .NET, Qt, STL, Boost... etc?

Comment: Exactly which functions do you use that need synchronizing?

Comment: Seems to me like a simple "re-establish socket"-flag would do, set by thread B and checked/cleared by thread A.

Comment: How do you listen on socket in thread A, synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Create/start another thread A instance, passing it the new IP/port.  Set some flag in thread B, telling to exit itself and clean up if and when it ever wakes up.

Comment: Oh, if you want to gee things along a bit, close the listening socket on the old thread - it'll fail with some exception or error and the old thread A can then clean up itself and die.

Comment: In my first comment, I meant 'Set some flag in the old thread A'

Comment: Re: your flag.  Mods can't do that. You'll have to email team@stackoverflow and ask.  Most likely will take a long time before they get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a workflow such as:

```
// thread A
// receive packets on initial address
WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE); // wait for address change
// receive packets on the new address
```

and

```
// thread B
// do some work
// change IP address
SetEvent(event); // signal A to start receiving on the new address
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I'll make my comment an answer:

Create/start another thread A instance, passing it the new IP/port. Set some flag in the old thread A, telling to exit itself and clean up if and when it ever wakes up.

If you want to gee things along a bit, or you do this 'change socket' operation frequently, close the listening socket on the old thread A - it's accept() call will fail with some exception or error and the old thread A can then clean up itself and die.